# executing from command prompt works but not from batch file

Tags: batch-file, command

I am trying to set a variable in a batch file for next year's year, i. e., if the current year is `2016` I want the variable set to `2017`.

I now that I can get the value by using:

```
SET /a sum=%date:~6%+1
```

I tried to redirect the result to a file as follows:

```
SET /a sum=%date:~6%+1 >next_year.txt
```

If I run this from the command prompt then it works fine. But if I have this in a `.bat` file and run the file from the command prompt, the `next_year.txt` file gets created but there is no value in it.

I'm sure I'm missing something silly here but I'm going round in circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the design of `set /A` (therefore you cannot change it):

- In command prompt (`cmd`) context, `set /A` outputs the (last) result to the console window. For example, `set /A X=1+2` echoes the result `3` to the console, and `set /A x=1+2, y=x-1` echoes `2` (without trailing line-break, by the way).
- In contrast, in batch file context, the `set /A` command does not output anything.

To get the result of a `set /A` command line, you need to echo it explicitly in the next line, like `echo %X%`, referring to the first of the aforementioned examples. Of course you can redirect that into a file:

```
> "\path\to\file.txt" echo %X%
```